# Transfer of energy

Tags: energy, energy-conservation

If thermal energy is always being transferred from an object with high thermal energy to an object with low energy. Does that mean this also applies to other types of energy? For example, if two objects collide with one another, is kinetic energy always transferred from the object with higher kinetic energy to the object with lower kinetic energy?

Answer (score 1):

No. Imagine the two objects colliding head on. They might both stop on the spot and break apart. Their kinetic energies will then be spent on deforming the materials and will be converted into heat.

This is called an inelastic collision. If the collision is elastic, then the kinetic energies will indeed have to be conserved and you might see what you suggest. In general, I guess they what you suggest is true in cases where no energy conversions are taking place - which typically is the case in usual heat transfer processes.

Comment: "Their kinetic energies will then be spent on deforming the materials and will be converted into heat." This may imply that all the KE is lost, whereas I don't believe that is possible and be consistent with conservation of momentum. Don't the  broken parts in your example have momentum and KE?

Comment: @BobD If two equal objects with speeds $-v$ and $v$ collide, then they carry momentas $p_1=-mv$ and $p_2=mv$. The total momentum before the collision is $\sum p=0$. That they should be able to reach a complete standstill is not violating this conservation law.

Comment: Yes, but I was referring to the example of the parts breaking up.  All the kinetic energy is not spent in that case (you have the KEs of the fragments)

Comment: That depends on how they collide and how they deform and break apart. Why could the whole two objects collide and result in a final total momentum of zero, if each broken part couldn't?

Comment: Steeven, if you started your answer by referring to a perfectly inelastic head on collision between two equal mass objects having equal but opposite velocities,  I wouldn't have even commented.  But when you said they break apart I visualized fragments flying off in different directions, so that the initial KE is not "spent" in the collision. That's all.  Sorry if I caused confusion.

Answer (score 1):

> If thermal energy is always being transferred from an object with high
> thermal energy to an object with low energy.  Does that mean this also applies to other types of energy?

The transfer of thermal energy, called heat, is not between a high energy object and a low energy object. It is energy transfer from a higher temperature object to a lower temperature object.

The temperature of an object is due to the *average* molecular kinetic energy of all the molecules of the object, not the total kinetic energy. The total molecular kinetic energy is proportional to the amount of mass. So the total energy of the object at higher temperature may actually be less than the total energy of the lower temperature object depending on the relative masses and specific heats of the objects.

> For example, if two objects collide with one another, is kinetic
> energy always transferred from the object with higher kinetic energy
> to the object with lower kinetic energy?

First, the transfer of the macroscopic kinetic energy (the kinetic energy of the object as a whole) in a collision between objects is not the transfer of thermal energy. Technically, it is energy transfer by work.

In the case of a perfectly elastic collision, the higher KE object will transfer KE to the lower KE object. But in the case of a perfectly inelastic collision, where the objects stick together, there may be no transfer of KE to the lower KE object, or the final KE may be zero depending on the nature of the collision.

In general, for a perfectly inelastic collision, where the objects stick together and have the same final velocity $\vec V_f$, in order for momentum to be conserved, the final velocity $\vec V_f$ of the colliding objects is

$$\vec V_{f}=\frac{m_{1}\vec V_{1}+m_{2}\vec V_{2}}{m_{1}+m_{2}}$$

Where $\vec V_1$ and $\vec V_2$ are the initial velocities of $m_1$ and $m_2$.

A couple of special cases:

1. The mass of one of the objects is much greater than the other, for example, $m_{1}>>>m_2$ we have

$$\vec V_{f}=\vec V_1$$

This allows for the possibility of a higher KE object, $m_2$, not increasing the KE of a lower KE object, $m_1$.

2. For a head on collision between to equal masses having the same magnitude but opposite direction velocities, we have

$$\vec V_{f}=0$$

Resulting in all the initial KE converted to other forms (primarily heat).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The premise is incorrect.

> "*If thermal energy is always being transferred from an object with high thermal energy to an object with low energy.*"

It is not; a large, cold body (with high thermal energy—remember than energy is an [extensive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intensive_and_extensive_properties) quantity) does not heat a speck of hot matter (with low thermal energy). Quite the opposite.

Thermal energy is always transferred (if possible, with all else held equal) from an object with high **temperature** to an object with low temperature. Note that temperature is an [intensive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intensive_and_extensive_properties) quantity.

Given this modification, yes, the same thing broadly happens in other processes.

- When two objects strike each other, the stress (note that stress is an intensive quantity) applied by one on the other transfers energy in the form of strain energy (in the form of strain) and kinetic energy (in the form of speed).
- When two liquid films come into contact, the surface tension (intensive) applied by one on the other transfers surface energy (surface area).
- When two gases come into contact, the pressure (intensive) applied by one on the other does mechanical work (volume shift).
- When two materials come into contact, the chemical potential (intensive) applied by one on the other does chemical work (chemical reaction or phase change).

Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Transfer of thermal energy from a hot body (high thermal energy) to a cold body (low thermal energy) is due to the fact that the molecules in hot body have higher vibrational energies (for solids), higher vibrational, translational (for liquids) and higher vibrational, rotational and translational energies (for gases) and hence in the collision between the low kinetic energy molecules and high kinetic energy molecules, energy gets transferred from the hot to the cold body.

In fact, if you have an **elastic collision**, then kinetic energy is transferred from the high energy body to the low energy body.

Moreover, total energy is conserved at all scales in all collisions (be it elastic or inelastic). In inelastic collision, when two lumps of clay initially coming from opposite directions stick together, the macroscopic kinetic energy gets converted into microscopic kinetic energy of the molecules (people call it "energy dissipated as heat").